# Get lowest mac address

Tags: powershell

What is the best way to get the network adapter with the lowest mac address?  There are multiple network adapters named Intel(R) I210, just need the one with the lowest mac address.

```
$adapters = Get-NetAdapter -InterfaceDescription "Intel(R) I210*"

foreach ($adapter in $adapters) {
    Write-Host $adapter.MacAddress
    $lastMacSegment = $adapter.MacAddress.Split("-")[-1]
    Write-Host "Last segment $lastMacSegment"
    $dec = [Convert]::ToInt64($lastMacSegment, 16)
    Write-Host $dec
}

???
```

Comment: So basically you want to sort them based on the last segment, that's what you mean by lowest right?

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon The last segment would be acceptable, but ideally it would be the entire mac address

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Sort-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/sort-object?view=powershell-7.2) to sort the output from `Get-NetAdapter` based on the `.MacAddress` property and then get the *lowest Mac Address* based on that sort.

```
Get-NetAdapter "Intel(R) I210*" | Sort-Object MacAddress
```

For the *lowest* you would simply pipe it to `Select-Object -First 1`.

I was previously using `Sort-Object { [PhysicalAddress] $_.MacAddress }` however this is not even needed as [Lee_Dailey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3080908/lee-dailey) pointed out.

Comment: you can sort by the `.PermanentAddress` or the `.MacAddress` or the `.LinkLayerAddress` property without using the `[PhysicalAddress]` stuff. [*grin*]

Comment: duh, not sure why I thought it wouldn't be able to properly sort a string ‍♂️thanks @Lee_Dailey

Comment: you are most welcome! glad to help a tad ... [*grin*]